# How to move div to the center of the screen from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

There is the following code of main HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:8092/iframe.html"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And there is code of iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <div id="text">This just text</div>
    <button id="btn">Click</button>
    <div id="popup">Center</div>
    <script>
      document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
        alert('center');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my main file includes iframe. My question: is it possible to put div with id "popup" in center of the screen (not only iframe)? Domain of main file and domain of iframe are not the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is unclear as the title and the description don't seem to match. Aside from centering the popup div, what is the end purpose?  You mentioned domains. Is there any communication between the host page and the iframe?

Comment: I've created a simple prototype for my task, and the target of my question is to understand  ifis it possible or not to do it to center div from JS/CSS in iframe.

There is no communication between iframe and main site (you mean postMessage, right?)